# leaving the chroot in place if pdebuild fails?

Tags: continuous-integration, chroot, pdebuild

I am doing automated builds with pdebuild. Sometimes these builds fail.
In these cases I would like to keep the chroot to be able to investigate the cause of failure.
I was trying to run pdebuild with --debug, which is -according to pbuilder manpage - is expected to do just that, but it had no effect.
How can I tell pdebuild to leave the build environment in place?

Answer (score 1):

According to this `-mentors` [mailing list post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.mentors/64807), you can use the supplied `C10shell` hook:

```
cp /usr/share/doc/pbuilder/examples/C10shell path/to/hook/dir
```

(I use `cp` instead of `ln -s` only because I often edit the hooks myself.)

This will start an interactive shell upon failure.

Comment: Well, this won't work with an automated build. However I could backup the current status of the chroot from such a hook, and run other diagnostics. Thanks and +1.

Comment: @ÁrpádMagosányi Yeah, I wasn't sure whether you needed something non-interactive or not. But it sounds like this will help :)